# Is the Martian Manhunter's weakness to fire physical, or purely mental?

Tags: comics, dc-rebirth, martian-manhunter, dc

I'm getting conflicting information in the comics, but considering many are from differing eras, that's to be expected. In most Pre-Crisis comics, J'onn J'onzz, a green martian, has an aversion to fire that would **physically** cause him to lose powers, burn, and even [in some cases] take on a liquefied form. Post-Crisis, this seems to have been more of a psychological weakness; I myself have a Post-Crisis **Superman** Annual where Wave Rider views a possible future where Superman is a tyrant and, in a battle with Jonn,  Booster Gold and Fire, Jonn is trapped in a building with Fire's flames and dies of a heart attack [why they would team him with a heroe who's power is his **exact weakness** is BEYOND ME, but, story reasons...]

In the animated movie **Justice League: New Frontier** [a film made in the 2000s, but set in the 1950s], it's implied this is a *physical* weakness, as Batman said he could kill Jonn with a "penny matchbook", although when faced with fire in his "human" form, Jon seemed to "Freeze up" from a panic attack. In a later animated film, **Justice League:Doom,** Jon was infected with nanites which burned with a phosphorous flame, and this too seemed to hurt him *bodily* while he'd had an earlier aversion to the small flames on a birthday cake.

On the series **Smallville** it was shown several times that Jon Jones has an intense "fear" of fire,  which could paralyze him from moving, but not necessarily stop him from using his powers. However, when he flew almost into the sun in order to bring Clark to it to jump-start his powers and save his [Clark's] life, it *seemed* as though it had a physical effect. Quote Jonn:

> The burning sun may strengthen *you,* but it has the opposite effect on *me* ... it *stripped me of my powers,* trapping me in this form.

Near is I can figure it, as the pure fires of the sun must have damaged his Martian cellular structure, and without the ability to get into his own atmosphere, he wasn't able to heal himself; this was corrected via magical transportation to Mars by Dr. Fate later in the series.

I'm aware since the White Martian saga that this aversion to fire was implanted in all the martian race, green and white, on a genetic level by the Guardians of the Universe. This was done to prevent the powerful Martians from combining into a powerful, nigh unstoppable war-like race/form known as The Burning, but again, this was somewhat retconned; while having no "real" physical affects, fire of a "psychic kind" can be detrimental to him.

So at this point, I'm uncertain if fire can still *physically* hurt J'onn...which makes very little sense, considering he can both move things with his mind, or alter his molecular density to beyond that of diamond, or even to exactly match that of nomax.... OR if it is more of a *psychological* issue which somehow prevents him from using his powers...even though he *himself* has a form of heat vision.

Can anyone answer this question in relation to the modern comics, please, especially Rebirth?